# General term for reactive vs real power

Tags: terminology

There are general terms for properties which are preserved in a physical process such as [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)) or [constant of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_of_motion). Is there some similar term for some property which accumulates or cause accumulating net effect which would generalize terms [reactive/real power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power#Real_power) ? Perhaps more rigorously we can say that it is action which efficiently change some [state variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_variable) (?).

For example a rocket in central gravity field accumulates kinetic energy by action of thruster tangential to orbit but radial component of thrust has only minor effect on kinetic energy of the rocket. I see strong analogy between reactive/real power of AC circuit, and I would like to summarize both under the same term.

Answer (score 0):

> I see strong analogy between reactive/real power of AC circuit

Real power in an AC circuit is due to resistance which is dissipative.  I don't see any dissipation in your rocket example.

Further, AC circuit analysis assumes sinusoidal steady state which requires that the sources are sinusoidal.  But a rocket thruster doesn't provide a sinusoidal forcing function.

Perhaps you can add some details to your question that will clarify what you have in mind.

Comment: the projection of thrust in x,y direction on circular orbit is also sinusoidal. In that case that circular motion can be seen as harmonic oscilator. In the same way as AC circuit does real work if voltage is in phase with current, in case of rocket or of mechanical pendulum real work is done when force is in phase with velocity. But I did not want to be very specific since I want general term going beyond these simple examples.